# Displaying array as tree structure in php

Tags: php, arrays, tree

I have an array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => dir0|file0.txt
    [1] => dir0|file1.txt
    [2] => dir1|file2.txt
    [3] => dir1|filea.txt
    [4] => dir2|fileb.txt
)
```

I would like it to be displayed as a tree, such as:

```
dir0
  file0.txt
  file1.txt
dir1 
  file2.txt
  filea.txt
dir2
  fileb.txt
```

Can any one explain how I can do that?

**Edit:** Updated for multidimentional array:

```
$paths[0][0] = 'dir0|file0.txt';
$paths[0][1] = 400;
$paths[1][0] = 'dir0|filea.txt';
$paths[1][1] = 500;
$paths[2][0] = 'dir1|file1.txt';
$paths[2][1] = 600;
$paths[3][0] = 'dir1|fileb.txt';
$paths[3][1] = 700;
$paths[4][0] = 'dir2|filec.txt';
$paths[4][1] = 700;
```

I would like the output to be:

```
dir0 (900)
  file0.txt (400)
  filea.txt (500)
dir1 (1300)
  file1.txt(600)
  fileb.txt (700)
dir2 (700)
  filec.txt (700)
```

The values need to be added and displayed in root.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way would be to reformat the array so the keys were the directories, and the array values were arrays containing file names, like so:

```
$array = array( ..);
$reformatted = array();
foreach( $array as $k => $v) {
    list( $key, $value) = explode( '|', $v);
    if( !isset( $reformatted[$key])) 
        $reformatted[$key] = array();
    $reformatted[$key][] = $value;
}
```

Then you just have to iterate over the new array, like so:

```
foreach( $reformatted as $dir => $files) {
    echo $dir . "\n";
    foreach( $files as $file)
        echo "\t" . $file . "\n";
}
```

This [outputs](http://viper-7.com/2kXKoE):

```
dir0
    file0.txt
    file1.txt
dir1
    file2.txt
    filea.txt
dir2
    fileb.txt
```

Note that this will only work for plain text environment (such as `<pre></pre>`, like in the demo). Otherwise, you'll need to use `<br />` instead of `\n` for line breaks, or use an ordered or unordered list.

**For HTML output, use this,** whose output can be [seen here](http://viper-7.com/jBVGjX)

```
echo '<ul>';
foreach( $reformatted as $dir => $files) {
    echo "<li>$dir</li>";
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach( $files as $file)
        echo "<li>$file</li>";
    echo '</ul>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Generates:

- dir0
  - file0.txt
  - file1.txt
- dir1
  - file2.txt
  - filea.txt
- dir2
  - fileb.txt

For your updated array, here is the solution:

```
$reformatted = array(); $weights = array();
foreach( $paths as $k => $v) {
    list( $key, $value) = explode( '|', $v[0]);

    if( !isset( $reformatted[$key])) 
        $reformatted[$key] = array();

    if( !isset( $weights[$key]))
        $weights[$key] = 0;

    $reformatted[$key][] = array( $value, $v[1]);
    $weights[$key] += $v[1];    
}

foreach( $reformatted as $dir => $files) {
    echo $dir . ' (' . $weights[$dir] . ")\n";
    foreach( $files as $file)
        echo "\t" . $file[0] . ' (' . $file[1] . ")\n";
}
```

This [outputs](http://viper-7.com/HFAFjX):

```
dir0 (900)
    file0.txt (400)
    filea.txt (500)
dir1 (1300)
    file1.txt (600)
    fileb.txt (700)
dir2 (700)
    filec.txt (700)
```

I'll leave it up to you to translate that into HTML if necessary.

Comment: how about if it a two dimensional array ?

Comment: You'd need to update your question with an example of the array.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a loop and do this.

```
 <?php
  $directories = array();
  foreach($arr as $val)
  {
     $pair = explode('|', $val);
     if(!isset($directories[$pair[0]])) { $directories[$pair[0]] = array(); }
     $directories[$pair[0]][] = $pair[1];
  }
  print_r($directories);
```

That will reorganize your array and then print_r it, showing you the new structure.
Then you can do this:

```
    <?php
    foreach($directories as $directory => $files)
    {
      echo "$directory<br><ul>";
      foreach($files as $file)
      {
          echo "<li>$file</li>";
      }
      echo "</ul>";
  }
```