# Unable to fetch values from json array tree in codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, json, codeigniter

I have following array tree in json which is passed to view in a variable

```
   [{
       "root":"0",
       "id":"19",
       "name":"Rose",
       "childs":[{
                    "root":"19"
                    "id":"22",
                    "name":"Ceema",
                    "childs":[{
                                 "root":"22",
                                 "id":"49",
                                 "name":"Chandar"

                              },
                              {
                                 "root":"22",
                                 "id":"50",
                                 "name":"Carol"
                              }]
            },
            {
                "root":"19",
                "id":"23",
                "name":"Ben"
            }]
   }]
```

now i want that at first it displays the name of array with root 0, when we click on that name, it shows the name contained in arrays within child(if it has any).
M not so good with json, so please help!

Comment: yes i m sending this array to view using json_ecnode();

Comment: Sorry but not getting what you want to do...

Comment: I want a button in the middle of screen on which name given in the array with root 0 is displayed

Comment: use `json_decode` to convert into multidimensional array.

Comment: When we click on that button, it shows more buttons with names given in arrays of child of root 0

Comment: I think it should be done with javascript but not sure how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **json_decode()** function in php or if you want to do it in javascript **JSON.parse**

This will give you result in array and rest things you need to do or find the code for it.

Comment: Thanks! Let me try :)

Comment: answer in this question might help you- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11214011/displaying-array-as-tree-structure-in-php

Comment: Thanks but this is little confusing

Comment: M trying with JSON.parse because later on i have to use ajax also to submit the values